# issue with jquery validation error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 3 radio groups each having 'yes' and 'no' value. Beside each of those radio groups there are 2 dropdown menus 'colour' and 'shade'.

PROBLEM:
When I select yes or no for radio button and nothing for the two drop downs and click submit i get an error 'Please select colour and shade for (USER)'. This is how I want it but when i click ok on this error I get please select attendance for USER2 immediately after. How do i remove this as I only want the first error displayed.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Have you tried else if?

Comment: yes i have didnt work either :(

Comment: Well, Don seems to have nailed it!

Comment: Well, you have two lines in your code starting with " $("input:submit").click(function()". Why not combine these two blocks? That should fix it

Comment: @AmitBhargava Please see revised code. With that code I am not getting any error if i do not select any radio buttons

Comment: var retVal = true; retVal = validate(1); return retVal; Replace those statements with a single statement: validate(1)

Comment: @AmitBhargava it still doing what it did originally

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. But Don's fiddle seems to work.

Comment: @AmitBhargava it clicked with me my id of button was actually submit not button OMG. working now thanks

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have 2 blocks running on `input:submit.click()`. So each time the button is pressed, it is running each block.

Comment: Can you add your HTML and generated Javascript (i.e. without the php blocks) on jsfiddle.net so we can see it? You should be able to move the code from the second block into the validate() function.

Comment: Strangely, when I added the jQuery code from your question (I tweaked it a bit to remove the PHP and to declare `namesArray`) it actually works the way you want it. http://jsfiddle.net/8CTnD/1/

Comment: I dont think the problem lies with php as i just removed it and it is still doing it

Comment: I don't think so either I just had to replace it with something static. Is this page live on the internet somewhere so we can see it in action instead?

Comment: how would I break it so that it does not get passed the first 3 validations if it is triggered?

Comment: maybe not see in your fsfiddle selected yes and then select a colour and shade and click submit. See the way it does not come up and error please select attendance....

Comment: got rid of the double error but now the none of the validation error work if radio buttons left blank. My code is exactly like yours in jsfiddle. Try running it without anything selected...no error appears

Comment: You'll need some more code to require a selection in each of the radio buttons. Right now, there is only an error if "Yes" is selected without selections in the 2 corresponding selectboxes.